# How to detect input field value changes in angular with each value insertion?

Tags: javascript, angular, angularjs-directive, event-handling, web-frontend

How to detect input field value changes immediately without pressing enter button in angular  ?

I was trying to trigger a function on a value change of input field in Angular. Initially I used Keypress event, that was detecting the insertion the input field correctly, but even I used backspace to remove any character from the value, it didn't trigger that function, which means that these changes went unnoticed. I was expecting that it would trigger that event on the each change or update of the value.

Comment: Can you provide some code or a stackblitz?

Answer (score 2):

### Using Input

---

**In HTML**

```
<input (input)="type($event)" type="text" />
```

**In TS**

```
 type(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
  }
```

### Using ngModel

---

**In HTML**

```
<input type="text" [ngModel]="mymodel" (ngModelChange)="valuechange($event)" />
```

**In TS**

```
mymodel:any
        
 valuechange(newValue) {
   this.mymodel = newValue;
   console.log(newValue)
 }
```

Demo Link :- [*Link*](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-atiszh?devToolsHeight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: It's more "Angular way" use `[(ngModel)]`. This "two ways binding" allow give value to a variable declare in .ts

Comment: i have just added it's code also @Eliseo

Answer (score 1):

you can use [(ngModel)]. I suggest you "split" the "bannana sintax"

```
<input matInput placeholder="Word" 
          [ngModel]="search" 
          (ngModelChange)="search=$event;doSomething($event)">

doSomething(value:string)
{
    console.log(value)
}
```

Another ways can be

```
<!--see that the event "input" return a "generic event"
    so you use $event.target.value to "reach" the value-->
<input matInput placeholder="Word" 
          [(ngModel)]="search" 
          (input)="doSomething($event.target.value)">
```

Or

```
<input matInput placeholder="Word" 
          [(ngModel)]="search" 
          (ngModelChange)="doSomething($event)">
```

Answer (score 0):

By using two-binding and ngModelChange event, worked for me to detect all changes.
Sample code  :

```
     <input matInput placeholder="Word"
       [(ngModel)]="search"
       (ngModelChange)="filterTbl()"
       matTooltip="Filter Result">
```